# How to include virtual fields in find with CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to add an isOnline field for users which does not exists in the database. Is there a way In can return isOnline as a virtual field? I have tried adding this to the User entity:

```
protected function _getIsOnline() {
    return true;
}
```

But when I do a `$user->find('all', [])` the field is not included. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Could this be due to a cached model/entity? Have you tried clearing cakes Caches?

Comment: What do you mean by "not included"? If you're converting to JSON, for example, your virtual field won't be included unless you've also added it to the `$_virtual` array in the entity. If you're dumping debug output, it won't be included even if it's in `$_virtual`. But if you output the field itself, it should work as you have it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt It is not include in my JSON. But not only that it is not on the object returned from the find call. I have put a break point and looked at all of the fields, isOnline is not included.

Comment: As I said, it won't be in any debug output. And it won't be in the JSON unless you include the field name in the `$_virtual` array. See [Exposing Virtual Properties](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#exposing-virtual-properties) in the manual.

Comment: Some virtual fields are compute- or database-intensive, so they are not always generated, only when required, for example if you convert to JSON or array output, or when you directly reference the property via something like `$user->isOnline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use use virtual fields within the query object. Any filtering would have to take place after retrieving the data from the query. Virtual fields are lazy loaded, so they do not exist until required.

Comment: For me the problem was disabledHydration on query - without object mapping the virtual fields are not processed.