# Cakephp How Can I add virtual field in select query?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

In front end I have to display all favorites icon green depend on is_fav status true.

So, I'm trying to create an API, Where I want to add is_fav with all product entity. My expected json will looks like

```
{
       "id": 14,
       "title": "Orange",
       "price": 600,
       "is_fav" : true
}
```

So, I'm trying to add is_fav with product entities , where is_fav is a virtual function.

In entity I have tried like below

```
protected function _getIsFav()
{
    //to DO : I will write a query here 
    return true;
}
```

In query I have tried to add in query in select like below

```
$favorites = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()
            ->get( 'Products' )
            ->find()
            ->select([
                'id',
                'Products.id',
                'Products.title',
                'Products.price',
                'is_fav' => $this->is_fav,  //getting error 
            ])
;
```

I'm getting error, How can I add is_fav with product entities. Is it possible ? If not how can I add is_fav like my json ?

Comment: This is not how virtual fields work in Cake 3.x and higher.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cakephp: exposed virtual field are not included in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60026617/cakephp-exposed-virtual-field-are-not-included-in-query)

Comment: take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954396/1934672

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. CakePHP 4.3

In the Entity

```
protected $_virtual = ['label'];

protected function _getLabel()
{
    return $this->name . ' - (' . $this->company. ')';
}
```

The query does not mention the virtual field

```
    $customers = $this->Users->find()
        ->select(['id', 'name', 'company'])
        ->contain(['Roles' => function ($q) {
            return $q->select(['id','name','level','price_level'])
            ->where(['Roles.level' => 50]);
        }])
        ->order('Users.name');
```

and then the JSON that output

```
[
    {
        "id": 1019,
        "name": "Abby xxxx",
        "company": "Abby yyy",
        "role": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Practitioner",
            "level": 50,
            "price_level": 2
        },
        "label": "Abby xxxx - (Abby yyy)"
    }
]
```

Comment: **Note**: for CakePHP5 specify **array**, i.e. `protected array $_virtual`, otherwise *Fatal error: Type of $_virtual must be array (as in class Cake\ORM\Entity)*